# My reload script is not working (Unity3D) it reload when I press r key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

'''

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Reload : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Ammo = 300;
    public float Clip = 30;
    void fire()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && Clip < 0)
        {
            Clip -= 1;
        }
    }
    void reload()
    {
        if (Clip < 30 && Input.GetKey("r"))
        {
            Clip = 30;
        }
        if (Clip > 30)
        {
            Clip = 30;
        }
    }
}
```

'''

this is the script I wrote myself and for some reason, it's not working. If I press my left mouse button or the "r" key it doesn't do what it's supposed to do I can see in my inspector window that whenever I press "r" key it doesn't reload(after changing it's value to something like 20). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just a side optimization note, in your reload method, if the end result is that the player's `Clip` is reset to `30`, you can remove the if/else conditions.

Comment: well are `fire` and `reload` called anywhere ..? so far you just declared two methods but never use them anywhere ... Probably in `private void Update(){ fire(); reload(); }` -> `Update` is a "magic" method called by Unity every frame

Comment: Where is `Clip` set? Currently none of your conditions will trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I am idiot guys. You just need to call it in the Update method. Thanks @DerHugo although I figured it out myself.
For someone in need this should help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Reload : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Ammo = 300;
    public float Clip = 30;
    public void Update()
    {
        //reload
        if (Clip < 30 && Input.GetKey("r"))
        {
            Clip = 30;
            Debug.Log("reload");
        }
        if (Clip > 30)
        {
            Clip = 30;
        }
        //fire
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && Clip > 0)
        {
            Clip -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

But now a new problem arises if I press lmb(leftmousebutton) it just captures for a frame lowers the clip size by 2-3 in a single click.